# How to data binding with by viewModels

Tags: android, android-databinding

The code I tried to use viewModel extension library to data binding in fragment, but the error happened in compile time show that the method `by viewModels()` can not be used in normal binding way.

```
// the library androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx

import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels

class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()  // I can use viewModelFactory to set the binding. But when change to this way, it can not be compile correctly.

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = FragmentMyBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
    ...
}
```

The error.

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the 
current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser
compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Tool 
version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime 
version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does 
not match the current runtime version 4.7.1 
Cannot find
import com.example.app.databinding.FragmentMyBindingImpl;
```

Comment: I guess there is a problem in your fragment XML part that makes this error, just make sure that your code has no error in somewhere else because sometimes this kind of error may be irrelevant.
 and upload your XML file too,

Comment: is your viewModel attached to the activity lifecycle?

Comment: I use one activity and many fragment inter-change, this viewModel in one fragment. I check the xml file, they are all the same as I using viewModelFactory before, so I think the error happened in `by viewModel()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The returned view of the onCreateView function should be the root view of your data binding generated class.

try to use this code

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {

private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
lateinit var binding: FragmentMyBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false)
    return binding.root
}


override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    binding.viewModel = viewModel

}
```